# 400OK - JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected character (n) at position - GCM SEND NOTIFICATION

Tags: android, json, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I m using GCM Server to send Push notification,
Well My code was working Just fine, until today I wanted to add some features to push  notifications,
I m able to generate notification key , but when i try to send data using notification key doesn't work , however it works fine while I use the registration ID.
to illustrate the problem I m having , here is an example of my request,

**Using Notification Key**

```
{
  "data": {
    "message": "ciao"
  },
  "notification_key":"APA91bHBwknl5VxdBTXZNpnUQ6mEyMZgeypyrYeN4JyCDDKNX1BgE7vO......."
}
```

**And This is the response I am getting**

```
HTTP/1.1 400 OK
status: 400
alternate-protocol: 443:quic,p=1
cache-control: private, max-age=0
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 79
content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
date: Sun, 17 May 2015 10:16:12 GMT
expires: Sun, 17 May 2015 10:16:12 GMT
server: GSE
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected character (n) at position 39.
```

**This One using registration ID, request**

```
{
  "registration_ids" : ["APA91bEHJV9JRViw5Ly6r0FE1rowxUWgu0TEjWkz4gy95Eb6m7WmTazHno7-odGSdLqdLhhF5l9QKjgEdmS8LknIa5e4NaxXC0PpLTXxDyGGXRhxkdle5sBZ..."],
  "data" : {
    "message":"Hello"
  },
}
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
status: 200 OK
version: HTTP/1.1
alternate-protocol: 443:quic,p=1
cache-control: private, max-age=0
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 138
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
date: Sun, 17 May 2015 09:41:32 GMT
expires: Sun, 17 May 2015 09:41:32 GMT
server: GSE
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

{"multicast_id":7352560529736354945,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1431855692805445%af3e3e4bf9fd7ecd"}]}
```

I really don't understand what's happening, Am I the only one getting this error.
Because I m pretty sure I m not doing anything wrong , and I made sure to read the documentation very carefully.

Comment: That would be exceed a character limit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,Actually first i thought about it , and I noticed that I m generating longer Notification Keys compared to what i used to get .still I m not the one who controls the length of the generated notifications Keys ,i get it from Google messaging server using through "create" notification request .

Comment: Apparently something was wrong with the GCM Server .I have been trying to send notifications using notification key for the past two days , it didn't work at all, but now it s working fine .